# Como não permitir que o usuário digite números e somente texto no Java?

Tags: java

Estou criando um programa sobre cadastro em que o usuário tem que colocar nome,senha,e-mail,etc.Mas nos campos como por exemplo nome eu quero que o usuário só possa colocar texto em vez de números,e que caso ele coloque um número apareça uma mensagem para falar que ele não pode colocar números e sim somente digitar em forma de texto.
Como é possível fazer isto ? Com um método que verifica a length do campo ?
Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço,caso for preciso eu coloco o código.

Aqui está o código :

```
String nome,email;
double password,account; 

nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual seu nome ? ");
email = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual seu email ?");
account = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite uma account : "));
password = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite um password : "));
```

Comment: Java web ou desktop?

Comment: Coloque o código, sempre.

Comment: Olá Falion. É um programa com cliente Desktop, Console ou Web? Quais tecnologias do Java você está usando? O que você já fez? Por favor poste um pedaço de código relevante indicando exatamente que campo você gostaria de validar.

Comment: Por curiosidade, seu programa está usando JOptionPane pra criar seu programa? O que você quer, tem que ser feito num JPanel com JTextField's, Jlabel's e etc. Veja esse exemplo de um [form em swing](http://www.edu4java.com/en/swing/swing3.html)

Comment: Sim o programa esta utilizando JOptionPane

Comment: Então,é Java desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bom, é simples. Pelo código que você colocou e pelo JOPtionPane vejo que estais trabalhando com Java SE.

Você pode criar um método para validar se o input do usuário contém apenas texto (por texto entende-se apenas caracteres alfabéticos) através de regex.

**Regular Expression** (regex) nada mais é que uma sequência de caracteres que definem um padrão de busca em Strings, você pode criar expressões para validar uma infinidade de padrões, como emails, endereços de sites, cpfs, etc.. [para saber mais](http://aurelio.net/regex).

Vou dar duas opções de expressões para iniciar seus estudos sobre o assunto e te ajudar a alcançar o objetivo.

1. **A primeira:** "[a-zA-Z\s]+" Nesta você irá validar apenas letras minúsculas(a-z), maiúsculas(A-Z) e espaços em branco(\s). O caracter + indica que essa combinação pode ocorrer 1 ou mais vezes. Confira o exemplo aplicado [aqui](http://regexr.com/3cd9n), como você perceberá essa expressão não vai aceitar caracteres especiais ou acentos e caso você queira que sejam aceitos deixarei que você mesmo pesquise, um [link](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/acentuacao.html) para começar.
2. **A segunda:** "[^\d]+" Essa expressão é mais fácil caso você só não queira aceitar número e deseja aceitar qualquer outro tipo de caractere. O caractere ^ é utilizado para negar o caractere \d que indica os dígitos. [Veja o exemplo em prática](http://regexr.com/3cd9q).

Para aplicar em java você precisa apenas de uma String para poder chamar o método matches da classe, veja um exemplo de método:

```
public boolean matchesOnlyText(String text) {
    return text.matches("[^\\d]+"); //Passa para o método matches a regex
    //Se tiver número na string irá retornar falso
    //Note o uso de duas \\, uma sendo obrigatória para servir de caractere de escape
}
```

Agora de acordo com o seu próprio exemplo de código, pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual seu nome ? ");
if(!matchesOnlyText(nome)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você não pode inserir números no nome.");
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, pelo menos a dar início em seus estudos de regex.

Comment: Nossa,muito obrigado por ter passado este conteúdo,me ajudou muito.Eu estava exatamente a procurar isto,eu já tinha visto algo sobre,mas não tão bem explicado,enfim,obrigado.

Comment: Só que deu um erro quando fui colocar uma parte que você explicou,da este erro : "Cannot make a static reference to a non method matchesOnlyText(String) from the type Cadastro."

Comment: Você deve estar tentando acessar um método não static de dentro do método main que é static, para isso ser possível você deve colocar o modificador static no método matchesOnlyText OU acessá-lo através de uma referência de Cadastro (new Cadastro());

Comment: Estou colocando o código do if dentro do método main,e o método matchesOnlyText fora do main.

Comment: Então, conforme eu disse você tem duas opções colocar o modificador static no método matchesOnlyText, ficando "public static boolean matchesOnlyText()" OU antes de tentar utilizar o método criar uma variável de referência da classe e acessá-lo através dela, por exemplo c = new Cadastro e depois c.matchesOnlyText(). Se a resposta te ajudou marque ela como melhor resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Já marquei amigo como melhor resposta,muito obrigado pela ajuda.Abraços.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode monitorar o que o usuário está digitando através do evento "KeyTyped" de um jTexfField e lá fazer os devidos tratamentos conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
private void tfNomeUsuarioKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
//Na variável "c" armazenamos o que o usuário digitou    
char c=evt.getKeyChar();

//Aqui verificamos se o que foi digitado é um número, um backspace ou um delete. Se for, consumimos o evento, ou seja, o jTextField não receberá o valor digitado
if((Character.isDigit(c) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
        evt.consume();
    }                
}
```

Comment: Tentei utilizar este teu código,e funcionou a parte do if,mas na parte do tfNomeUsuarioKeyTyped ele da um erro.

Comment: Aparece este erro : "vod is an invalid type for the variable tfNomeUsuarioKeyTyped.'

Comment: Para usar o código que dei de exemplo você precisa ter um jForm e adicionar nele um jTextField com o nome "tfNomeUsuario". Só assim você poderá ter um evento chamado "tfNomeUsuarioKeyTyped".

Comment: Okay,muito obrigado pela explicação e pela ajuda.